# What is the required setup of Travis when using webpacker on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, travis-ci, webpacker

I am using travis for the first time and I don't know how to correctly add webpacker on it?

Here is what I have for now in **.travis.yml**

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.4.4

addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

before_install:
  - "echo 'gem: --no-document' > ~/.gemrc"
  - "echo '--colour' > ~/.rspec"
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

before_script:
  - bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

Here is the build error

```
 $ bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
  Webpacker is installed  
  Using /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
  Compiling…
  Compilation failed:
  /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:11:in `exec': No such file or directory - /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/node_modules/.bin/webpack (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:11:in `block in run'
    from /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:10:in `chdir'
    from /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:10:in `run'
    from /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
    from ./bin/webpack:15:in `<main>'
  The command "bundle exec rails webpacker:compile" failed and exited with 1 during .
  Your build has been stopped.
```

`No such file or directory - /home/travis/build/bill/ivan/node_modules/.bin/webpack (Errno::ENOENT)`
it's in my rails app tought

Comment: shouldn't you run `rails webpacker:install` before `rails webpacker:compile` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well maybe it could help someone else: so here the setup that is finally working

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.4.4

addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

before_install:
  - "echo 'gem: --no-document' > ~/.gemrc"
  - "echo '--colour' > ~/.rspec"
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

before_script:
  - bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
  yarn: true

install:
  - bundle install
  - nvm install node
  - node -v
  - npm i -g yarn
  - yarn

script:
  - bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
  - bundle exec rails spec
```